# iOS simulator not launching after Xcode 9.4 and Xamarin.iOS 11.12 update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

The iOS deploy process does not start while trying to debug my Xamarin.iOS application. There are no build/deploy errors. I can connect to the Mac through mac agent and see the list of the simulators. However nothing happens after the build succeeds. (See attached output log below)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: XFLearning, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>XFLearning -> E:\XFLearning\XFLearning\XFLearning\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\XFLearning.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: XFLearning.iOS, Configuration: Debug iPhoneSimulator ------
2>  Connecting to Mac server 10.16.86.129...
2>  Connecting to Mac server 10.16.86.129...
2>  XFLearning.iOS -> E:\XFLearning\XFLearning\XFLearning.iOS\bin\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\XFLearning.iOS.exe
2>  Detected signing identity:
2>    Bundle Id: com.yourcompany.XFLearning
2>    App Id: com.yourcompany.XFLearning
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Tried rebooting Mac and Windows and running VS as administrator. No Luck.
Any solutions will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "iOS 11.12 update"  What versions of Xcode and iOS are you using?

Comment: @Cobra I meant I updated to Xamarin.iOS 11.12 version. Xcode version is 9.4.  Mac OS : High Sierra Version 10.13.5

Comment: Have you updated `Visual studio for mac` as well? And where did you launch the simulator, on mac or on windows?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT Yes, it's updated (Version 7.5.2) and I am running the simulator on Mac.

Comment: @19ashritha Try to close down simulator  and Xcode , run the application again.

Comment: Tried. No luck. I see that the deploy process does not start at all. It stops after build succeeds. I tried deploying another solution. It says "Deploy: 0 succeeded; 0 failed; 0 skipped".

Comment: Try to solve `Warning MSB3277` first , here is [workaround](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1261), maybe it affects the deploy process.

Comment: Updated question with output log from another solution where the issue exists

Comment: Have you checked Device log to find something useful?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT Device logs are empty. I do not see any devices to view the logs.

Comment: The issue is resolved after installing the new Visual studio update 15.7.4 which I got today. Thanks